# Load multiple SingleValueEvents at once with Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to start a Fragment with information I have to get from the Firebase database when I click the button. For the sake of an example, say I want to open a user profile and I need to load all data from `database > users > uid` AND I need information from `database > messages` (e.g. the posts of the user).

---

Now my approach would be this:

(The following code is a part of the `@Override public void onClick(View v) { }` method of the button that shall start the Fragment)

```
dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                       User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                       // start the fragment here ...
                }
});
```

But since I need information from `database > messages` as well, I'm not sure how to do this in a good way. The following would be possible:

(The following code is a part of the `@Override public void onClick(View v) { }` method of the button that shall start the Fragment)

```
dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                       User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                       // just add another listener on the other reference
                       dbRef_2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                      MessagesInfo message = snapshot.getValue(MessagesInfo.class);

                                      // start the fragment here ...
                               }
                      });
               }
});
```

---

But this seems not to be the best way to do it since we just got two SingleValueEvent listeners nested. And if we'd need more information, like 10 different database "locations", we'd need to nest 10 of these listeners.

So what is a good way?

Comment: Nesting listeners looks fine to me. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: As Frank van Puffelen commented before, there's nothing wrong with nested listeners. What is the problem, or what exactly are you afraid of?

Comment: Okay, since I'm new to Firebase I wasn't sure. I thought there is a way to put all "quieries" in one method, so you don't need 10 `@Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) { }` but only one for all of them. That would seem much more elegant to me. However, if this is fine, the question is answered, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no method to fetch multiple locations at once, you could do this with a custom script if you are expecting to re-use it multiple times but it would always result in a loop that fetches each item.

It's also important to note that the order in which the queries were sent is also the order in which the server processes them.